# Finding center of a given group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

How can find the center of SmallGroup($64$,$41$)=$(\mathbb Z_{16}\rtimes\mathbb Z_2)\rtimes \mathbb Z_2$ with the following presentation without using GAP?

$$\langle F_1,F_2\mid F_2^2, F_1^4, F_1F_2F_1^2F_2F_1^{-1}F_2F_1^2F_2, (F_1F_2)^2F_1^{-1}(F_1^{-1}F_2)^2F_1,
  (F_2F_1F_2F_1^{-1})^2(F_2F_1^{-1})^2(F_2F_1)^2\rangle$$

*Added by Derek Holt:* Here is a presentation of the group that might be more amenable to hand calculation.

$$\langle x,y,z \mid x^{16}=y^2=z^2=1, x^y=x^9, x^z=x^{-1}y, y^z=x^8y \rangle.$$

Comment: You should first begin by identifying the underlying morphisms to the automorphism groups for both semi-direct products then doing it "by hands" does not seem such a bad choice, IMHO...

Comment: No way to find it without using GAP since one should call `SmallGroup(64,41)` first to find more details about the group. There are three groups of order 64 for which `StructureDescription` returns `(C16 : C2) : C2`. There are several ways to form semidirect product so one needs GAP to find out which one is in this group. Please edit the question to add the presentation of the group.

Comment: This looks like a computer-generated presentation, and I can see little point in trying to do calculations with it by hand. Following Clement Guerin's suggestion, it would be more sensible to use GAP to determine the homomorphisms in the semidirect products, and to use that information to do hand calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Holt's presentation: (we write $h^a=a^{-1}ha$, hence $h^{ab}=(h^a)^b$).

Centralizer of $x$ contains $\langle x\rangle$, but it does not contain $y$ and $z$. Can it contain $yz$?

$$x^{yz}=(x^y)^z=(x^9)^z=(x^z)^9=(x^{-1}y)^9\neq x$$
since there will be a factor of $y$ in the expansion [this can be seen by explicit calculation: 
$$(x^{-1}y).(x^{-1}y)=x^{-1}.(y^{-1}x^{-1}y)=x^{-1}.x^{-9}=x^{-10}=x^{6}.$$
Hence $(x^{-1}y)^2=x^6$ and one can find $$(x^{-1}y)^9=[(x^{-1}y)^2]^4.(x^{-1}y)=x^{6.4}x^{-1}y=x^iy\neq x$$
Thus, centralizer of $x$ is $\langle x\rangle$, and hence $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of this group of order $16$; it can not be $\langle x\rangle$.

$z^{-1}x^2z=(x^{-1}y)^2=x^6\neq x^2.$
Hence $Z(G)\neq \langle x^2\rangle$.

Also, $z^{-1}x^4z=(x^{-1}y)^4=x^6.x^6=x^{12}\neq x^4$.

You can check that $x^8$ is in the center and it generates center: $Z(G)=\langle x^8\rangle\cong C_2$.